# Router In ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am pretty much new to React Js and stuck at an issue. There are 3 components under Root component, what I am trying to do is on click of any one of the three component I am trying to display another single component. But the issue is on click the desired component is loaded but the other components still remain on the page. Kindly suggest what needs to be done here.

```
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
     <Router>
      <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col s4">
          <AddCustomer />
        </div>
        <div className="col s4">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/viewcustomers" component={ViewCustomer} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <div className="col s2 offset-s1">
          <Notifications />
        </div>
        </div>
         <div className="row">
        <div className="col s4">
          < EditCustomer />
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </Router>
       </div>
```

Here on going to the path ViewCustomer is loaded but the other components are still present. I just wish to show one single component at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You should use the `Router` and `Route` components to render components for each view/page. The `Link` component from the `react-router-dom` library should be used to navigate between views. I would also suggest breaking away most of your HTML from the `Router` component.

```js
const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
       <Router>
         <Switch>
           <Route component={HomeView} exact path='/' />
           <Route component={CustomerView} exact path='/viewcustomers' />
         </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
);

// Component to render when at '/'
const HomeView = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col s4">
          <AddCustomer />
        </div>
        <div className="col s4">
          <Link to='/viewcustomers' />
        </div>
        <div className="col s2 offset-s1">
          <Notifications />
        </div>
        </div>
         <div className="row">
        <div className="col s4">
          <EditCustomer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Component to render when at '/viewcustomers'
const CustomerView = () => {
  // Create customer view here
  return 'customers';
};
```

Comment: Thank you it was quite helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Mate you got your understanding of react Router all messed up.
Issue with your code is that the other components (`<AddCustomer />`, and `<EditCustomer />`) are outside Switch and not tagged to any URL pattern, so rendered in which ever URL path you are in.

Your code should be something like below:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/addcustomers" component={AddCustomer} />
                <Route exact path="/viewcustomers" component={ViewCustomer} />
                <Route exact path="/editcustomers" component={EditCustomer} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```